# Browser/OS dependent event loop

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, event-loop

I stumbled upon the following event loop question:

```
function printing() {
    console.log(1);
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(2); }, 1); 
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(3); }, 2); 
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(4); }, 0); 
    console.log(5);
}
```

When I execute this function in Chrome, I get the output:

```
1 5 2 4 3
```

and in Firefox:

```
1 5 4 2 3
```

I guess this has something to do with the execution time for each statement. However, if thats the case, does this mean Firefox is faster in execution than Chrome?

Comment: The number after the comma is meaningless. It is in milliseconds so 0,1 or 2 milliseconds are not relevant

Comment: can you explain why? if it was 1000, 2000, 0 instead of 1, 2, 0, the output would be the same on both the browsers.

Comment: @TarunDugar https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Notes

"Historically browsers implement setTimeout() "clamping": successive setTimeout() calls with delay smaller than the "minimum delay" limit
are forced to use at least the minimum delay. The minimum delay,
DOM_MIN_TIMEOUT_VALUE, is 4 ms"

This explains why 0/1/2 don't matter. As for why they produce different results anyway, I don't know.

Comment: Google chrome uses the v8 engine and Firefox uses its own SpiderMonkey engine for javascript. The difference is probably the handling of the internal event queue. I would not recommend using low values for milliseconds. If you want things to be executed in a specific order just use functions or objects.

Comment: I am not using low values or anything. Just saw this question posted somewhere and it piqued my curiosity.